# Adding abilities to magic items

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

In regards to adding abilities I am confused as to whether improving a cloak of resistance +1 to a cloak of resistance +2 costs:

1. 1.5 times the cost of a +1

Or

2. The difference between a +1 and a +2.

The language of the DMG reads:

> A creator can add new magical abilities to a magic item with no restrictions. The cost to do this is the same as if the item was not magical. Thus, a +1 longsword can be made into a +2 vorpal longsword, with the cost to create it being equal to that of a +2 vorpal sword minus the cost of a +1 sword.
>
> If the item is one that occupies a specific place on a character’s body the cost of adding any additional ability to that item increases by 50%. For example, if a character adds the power to confer invisibility to her ring of protection +2, the cost of adding this ability is the same as for creating a ring of invisibility multiplied by 1.5.

Obviously this item occupies a body slot but this isn't really a new ability it is improving on the ability the item already has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you improve an existing magic item, you must pay the difference in value between the final item, and the item you started with.

Since you had a *cloak of resistance +1*, worth 1,000 gp, and you end up with a *cloak of resistance +2*, worth 4,000 gp, you have to pay 3,000 gp—the difference between them.

This doesn’t really have anything to do with the rules for adding new abilities, since the *cloak* isn’t getting a new ability, it’s just getting an improvement to an old ability. The second paragraph you quote is really about adding the effect of a separate item onto an already-existing item, and mirrors the rules for creating a custom magic item with multiple effects. In effect, it’s just a reminder that multiple-effect items have a 50% surcharge on effects after the first, and you have to account for that when determining the price difference you have to pay when improving an item.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73404/discussion-on-answer-by-kryan-adding-abilities-to-magic-items).